# Can I join my Xbox 360 friends from my Windows 10 PC?

Tags: xbox-360, pc

I'm trying to join my Xbox 360 friends on the PC but it just won't work. I've always wanted to try because my Xbox got red ring of death and I miss them.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

The Xbox 360 does not have Cross Platform play with Windows 10. If you wish to play with your friends on 360, just pick up a refurbished console from your local game store (they are extremely cheap now a days, I'd say less than 100$)